# Does a DataFrame with a single row have all the attributes of a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am slicing a DataFrame from a large DataFrame and daughter df  have only one row. Does a daughter df with a single row has same attributes like parent df?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,2),index=dates,columns=['col1','col2'])
df1=df.iloc[1]
type(df1)
>> pandas.core.series.Series
df1.columns
>>'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Is there a way I can use all attributes of pd.DataFrame on a pd.series ?

Comment: I tried and it does not work, my question is there a way we can use all attributes of df to pd.series.

Comment: As, all df with one row gets attributes of pd. Series by default.

Comment: Also you can use this: `df1.iloc[1].to_frame().T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly what you are looking for is a dataframe with one row:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df1).T                    # T -> transpose

                col1      col2
2013-01-02 -0.428913  1.265936
```

What happens when you do `df.iloc[1]` is that pandas converts that to a series, which is one-dimensional, and the columns become the index.  You can still do `df1['col1']`, but you can't do `df.columns` because a series is basically a column, and hence the old *columns* are now the new *index*

As a result, you can returns the former columns like this:

```
>>> df1.index.tolist()

['col1', 'col2']
```

This used to confuse me quite a bit.  I also expected `df.iloc[1]` to be a dataframe with one row, but it has always been the default behavior of pandas to automatically convert any one dimensional dataframe slice (whether row or column) to a series.  It's pretty natural for a row, but less so for a column (since the columns become the index), but really is not a problem once you understand what is happening.